# Why is Beta distribution curve assymetric?

Tags: probability

I saw a nice video about Beta distribution:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juF3r12nM5A&lc=UgzxQXHZ6LadiT5-wZR4AaABAg.9OYUU1mbOMi9OYrJ6By7HH

At first glance the problem used to illustrate the distribution seems symmetric, yet the curve is asymmetric. As the number of samples/observations increases, the curve narrows (as expected), and it appears that it also becomes more symmetric. Does anyone have an intuitive explanation?

Comment: "The problem used to illustrate the distribution seems symmetric." Why do you think this? The outcome of interest is 7 heads and 3 tails; this is more likely to come from a coin that favors heads than a coin that favors tails.

Comment: I am sure that there is a flaw in my understanding. I will have to watch the video again. My initial thought was "If 7-3 is the observed outcome, of course the 7-3 coin is the most likely one to generate this outcome. But naively I would thing that 6-4 and 8-2 coins should have the same likelihood, but they do not.

Answer (score 1):

It's not symmetric because of the pdf. The pdf of a $\text{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)$ distribution is $f(x)=\frac 1{\text{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)}x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}$. If $\alpha=\beta$ then the pdf is symmetric since $x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\alpha-1}=[x(1-x)]^{\alpha-1}$, otherwise the pdf is not symmetric.

It would not be accurate to say "as the number of samples/observations increases," because these aren't observations/samples; $\alpha,\beta$ are the parameters and the beta distribution models one observation.

The variance of a beta distribution is $\frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^2(\alpha+\beta+1)}$. As $\alpha,\beta$ get large the numerator is quadratic but the denominator is cubic, so the variance gets small quickly, causing the distribution to be concentrated around the mean. It looks symmetric about the mean because the variance is so small, but it isn't unless $\alpha=\beta$. Even though it might look symmetric when $\alpha,\beta$ are both large despite $\alpha\ne\beta$, the support of a beta distribution is $[0,1]$ so it is not truly "symmetric."

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful. However I am trying to get an intuition, gut-feel, for the asymmetry. I will have to watch the video again.